# How to deserialize object derived from Exception class using Json.net?

Tags: c#, json.net, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize object derived from Exception class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Error : Exception, ISerializable
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public Error() { }
}
```

```
Error error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Error >("json error obj string");
```

It gives me error:

> ISerializable type 'type' does not have a valid constructor.

Comment: Firstly, that's not the best way to extend the `Exception` class.

Comment: I'm surprised this even compiles since you haven't actually implemented the ISerializable interface.

Comment: ISerializable is defined on Exception class

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding a new constructor

```
public Error(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context){}
```

solved my problem.

Here complete code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Error : Exception
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public Error(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
    {
        if (info != null)
            this.ErrorMessage = info.GetString("ErrorMessage");
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info,StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);

        if (info != null)
            info.AddValue("ErrorMessage", this.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't check `info` on null, it's guarantee to be not-null :)

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can choose the OptIn strategy and define the properties that should be processed. In case of your example:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Error : Exception, ISerializable
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Error() { }
}
```

(Credits go to [this](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinStripe/blob/f3190dc8f648eeb9492650913db9ee5394606e72/XamarinStripe/StripeException.cs) library)

Answer (score 2):

Adding upon already provided nice answers;

If the exception is coming from a java based application, then above codes will fail.

For this, sth. like below may be done in the constructor;

```
public Error(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    if (info != null)
    {
        try
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = info.GetString("ErrorMessage");
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            **this.ErrorMessage = info.GetString("message");**
        }
    }
}
```