# Json.net fails when trying to deserialize a class that inherits from Exception

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class `SearchError` that inherits from `Exception`, and when ever I try to deserialize it from a valid json I get the following exception:

> ISerializable type 'SearchError' does not have a valid constructor. To correctly implement ISerializable a constructor that takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext parameters should be present. Path '', line 1, position 81.

I tried implementing the suggested missing constructor, and it didn't help.

This is the class after implementing the suggested constructor:

```
public class APIError : Exception
{
    [JsonProperty("error")]
    public string Error { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@http_status_code")]
    public int HttpStatusCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("warnings")]
    public List<string> Warnings { get; set; }

    public APIError(string error, int httpStatusCode, List<string> warnings) : base(error)
    {
        this.Error = error;
        this.HttpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
        this.Warnings = warnings;
    }

    public APIError(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        Error = (string)info.GetValue("error", typeof(string));
        HttpStatusCode = (int)info.GetValue("@http_status_code", typeof(int));
        Warnings = (List<string>)info.GetValue("warnings", typeof(List<string>));
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting the following exception (also in json.net code):

> Member 'ClassName' was not found.

I also tried implementing the same solution as in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422703/how-to-deserialize-object-derived-from-exception-class-using-json-net-c?rq=1), also got the same error above.

Comment: Share your code with people..

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3423037/504836

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423037/504836

Adding a new constructor

```cs
public Error(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context){}
```

solved my problem.

Here complete code:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Error : Exception
{

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public Error(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        if (info != null)
            this.ErrorMessage = info.GetString("ErrorMessage");
    }
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info,StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);

        if (info != null)
            info.AddValue("ErrorMessage", this.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: And this answer is useless, because you can't always just add a member to a class you don't own.  For example, I have this error trying to serialize a DbUpdateConcurrencyException thrown by the Entity Framework.  I have no control over that class or its members or what kind of instance is thrown.

Comment: @Lukasz Lysik is correct that the answer needs improving, but the best improvement is, in fact, a simplification. I have confirmed by stepping through code and saving the entire object and its properties that the only statement that must be in GetObjectData is the first one, base.GetObjectData(info, context); I have confirmed that every property gets populated, including the HRESULT, which is protected in .NET 2.0. The same holds for the constructor, too.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for this?  Is it a bug in JSON.NET? This is a horrible thing to add to hundreds of custom exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

As the error says, you are missing the serialization constructor:

```
public class SearchError : Exception
{
    public SearchError(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion which I already tried before, and now I'm getting some other exception (see above).

Comment: ": base(info, context)" throws an Exception "Member 'ClassName' was not found."

Comment: @joelnet: that's a problem with your code, not the answer. See MSDN link for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz6bzkbf.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: @joelnet: the example in the answer is working. We have dozens of classes that are configured this way. In addition, the MSDN link contains a working example. If you are having a specific problem with your code, then you should create a new question rather than downvoting an answer and then asking for help in comments.

Comment: The serialization constructor isn't always missing, it could be protected, such as with a DbUpdateConcurrencyException in the Entity Framework.  Also, this kind of answer isn't good, because it can't be applied if you don't own the class.  This seems more like a bug in JSON.NET at this point for it's inability to find a protected constructor.