# Is this a bug in JSON.NET or Entity Framework or am I doing something wrong while trying to serialize a list of Exceptions with JSON.NET?

Tags: exception, serialization, json.net, entity-framework-6

Got this error when trying to serialize a set of errors:

"ISerializable type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' does not have a valid constructor. To correctly implement ISerializable a constructor that takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext parameters should be present."

The constructor is in fact present in the base classes, but it is a `protected` member.

Someone asked to see the JSON:

```
{
    "$type": "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException, EntityFramework",
    "ClassName": "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException",
    "Message": "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.",
    "Data": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal, mscorlib"
    },
    "InnerException": {
        "$type": "System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException, EntityFramework",
        "ClassName": "System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException",
        "Message": "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.",
        "Data": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal, mscorlib"
        },
        "InnerException": null,
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateRowsAffected(Int64 rowsAffected, UpdateCommand source)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()",
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": "8\nValidateRowsAffected\nEntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator\nVoid ValidateRowsAffected(Int64, System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCommand)",
        "HResult": -2146233087,
        "Source": "EntityFramework",
        "WatsonBuckets": null
    },
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at REDACTED FOR DISPLAY ON STACKOVERFLOW",
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": "8\nSaveChanges\nEntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext\nInt32 SaveChanges()",
    "HResult": -2146233087,
    "Source": "EntityFramework",
    "WatsonBuckets": null,
    "SafeSerializationManager": {
        "$type": "System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager, mscorlib",
        "m_serializedStates": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
            "$values": [
                {
                    "$type": "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException+DbUpdateExceptionState, EntityFramework",
                    "InvolvesIndependentAssociations": false
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "CLR_SafeSerializationManager_RealType": "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
}
```

Here is example code that throws the exception:

```
var serializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace, //Necessary for subclassing list types
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException( "hi" ), serializationSettings );
if (json == null)
    return null;
var err = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException>( json, serializationSettings ); //throws error
```

This gets even stranger, because as one answer points out, this is an exceptional class in that it does not directly implement a constructor with the expected signature.  Instead, decompiling the class shows some kind of, quite literal, "justification" for NOT implementing the expected constructor...

```
/// <summary>
/// Exception thrown by <see cref="T:System.Data.Entity.DbContext" /> when the saving of changes to the database fails.
/// Note that state entries referenced by this exception are not serialized due to security and accesses to the
/// state entries after serialization will return null.
/// </summary>
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1032:ImplementStandardExceptionConstructors",
    Justification = "SerializeObjectState used instead")]
[Serializable]
public class DbUpdateException : DataException
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds exception state that will be serialized when the exception is serialized.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    private struct DbUpdateExceptionState : ISafeSerializationData
    {
```

Comment: Similar error here, but I cannot add a new constructor to a framework class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422703/how-to-deserialize-object-derived-from-exception-class-using-json-net-c

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186000/json-net-fails-when-trying-to-deserialize-a-class-that-inherits-from-exception

Comment: Interestingly, this answer...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3423037/88409 by user412265 on Aug 6 '10  10:47 appears to have been copied verbatim by another user here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18199702/88409 joelnet answered Aug 13 '13 at 2:28.

Comment: Can you add the JSON which is being deserialized? There are 3 public constructors defined for the this class. May be the JSON have information which is not matching any of the constructor. Check out the source of the exception class https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/DbUpdateConcurrencyException.cs

Comment: The constructor it's looking for, which accepts parameters of type SerializationInfo and StreamingContext, is present in the class as I've said.  The question is why JSON.NET is not able to find it.  Is there a setting somewhere?  Everything I've read suggests it should be able to find it, since these members are supposed to be declared protected/private for ISerializable.

Comment: The parameters you mentioned are actually part of [JsonException](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonException.htm) class. I'm assuming that JSON parser engine is treating the exception as JsonException and trying to deserialize it as instance of JsonException. or May be I'm wrong.

Comment: The embedded $type is clearly DbUpdateConcurrencyException, not JsonException.  There's absolutely no reason why the class JsonException should even be relevant.  I'm just trying to deserialize a type, and it's complaining that that type 'DbUpdateConcurrencyException' does not have a particular constructor (even though it in fact does).  The above JSON is exactly what JSON.NET output.  Using identical settings, it then cannot deserialize the thing it serialized.

Comment: My bad... Just tried to deserialize your json in a test. The reason seems to be that `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is derived from `DataException` which have the constructor which JSON engine is looking for.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I said.  The constructor is present in the class.  The question is, why can't JSON.NET find it?  Is it because it's defined in a parent class and not immediately on the most-derived class?   It's just not making much sense that it cannot find it.

Comment: See my answer. I tried to add more details around... And I'm blaming it to EF because they have supressed the rule     `CA1032:ImplementStandardExceptionConstructors` which enforces to have constructor with `SerializationInfo` and `StreamingContext` arguments.

Comment: I'm blaming JSON.NET (well, Microsoft too for pulling the rug out from under it), and here's why.  That exception to the rule was created because of new security restrictions in .NET 4 that prevent GetObjectData from running.  The ISafeSerializationData interface was created by Microsoft to workaround that issue.  In my opinion, JSON.NET should support that new interface, and it just currently does not.  So ,the ball's in JSON.NET's court, although Microsoft's the one who pulled this new class out of their ass without telling everyone.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISafeSerializationData'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771228/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-newtonsoft-json-linq-jobject-to-type-system-run)

Comment: Are you running in full trust, or do you need a solution that works in partial trust?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Json.net [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ISerializable),

> **ISerializable**
>
> Types that implement ISerializable are serialized as JSON objects. When serializing, only the values returned from ISerializable.GetObjectData are used; members on the type are ignored. When deserializing, the constructor with a SerializationInfo and StreamingContext is called, passing the JSON object's values.
>
> In situations where this behavior is not wanted, the JsonObjectAttribute can be placed on a .NET type that implements ISerializable to force it to be serialized as a normal JSON object.

Since you don't owe the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` class, A workaround could be to create a custom exception class which derive from the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` and Mark it with attribute `JsonObject`.

```
    [JsonObject]
    class CustomException : DbUpdateConcurrencyException
    {
        public CustomException(string message) : base(message) { }
    }

     // Serialize the new customException
     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
         new CustomException("hi"), serializationSettings);

     //shall not throw error now
     DbUpdateConcurrencyException err = 
          JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DbUpdateConcurrencyException>(json, serializationSettings);
```

This is a just a POC that I tried to make it work for JSON.Net. It makes no sense to create custom classes for all type which inherits `ISerializable` and doesn't have required constructor. May be you can try creating Castle core `DynamicProxy` generator to wrap the thrown exception which are `ISerializable` and mark them with `JsonObject` attribute on-the-fly before serializing them.

And you're right. Json.net is not able to find the protected constructor because inheritance goes like

```
DbUpdateConcurrencyException <- DbUpdateException <- DataException
```

And [DataException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataexception(v=vs.110).aspx) class have the Protected constructor which json.net is looking for. Every exception class in .Net framework which is derived from `SystemException` have this constructor as protected constructor but `DbUpdateException` && `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` doesn't have it. So you can guess who to blame now (IMO EF).

Following are the classes I found which have the standard serializable constructor missing and would throw exception during deserialization.

- EntitySqlException
- PropertyConstraintException
- DbUpdateConcurrencyException
- DbUpdateException
- ToolingException
- DbEntityValidationException
- CommandLineException

I wrote this issue to [EF team here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2895).

Comment: @triyanko did it help you somehow?

Comment: The first half, no. That documentation just states the obvious that JSON.NET respects the ISerializable interface and will serialize objects using that interface and its corresponding methods, when present. The ability to override that behavior to do member-wise serializiation (as if the ISerializable interface wasn't there) by placing a JsonObject attribute on the class is also irrelevant here, because, again, I don't own the class, so I'm not marking it with anything. Overridding it is not an option.

Comment: The second half is helpful.  After additional thought I realized that constructors can't really be inherited like other methods, since they're constructors and so they have to be on the top-level class in order to create an instance of it.  The fact that only those few classes fail to implement the constructor directly is odd. If you look at their implementation, the class is marked with this strange attribute:

Comment: /// <summary> /// Exception thrown by <see cref="T:System.Data.Entity.DbContext" /> when the saving of changes to the database fails. /// Note that state entries referenced by this exception are not serialized due to security and accesses to the /// state entries after serialization will return null. /// </summary> [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1032:ImplementStandardExceptionConstructors", Justification = "SerializeObjectState used instead")] [Serializable] That seems to justify the fact that it's not implementing standard constructor??? What is that all about!?

Comment: It seems to implement ISafeSerializationData instead, and is marked with a justification for doing so. I wouldn't bank on Microsoft changing anything, because it seems to have been done that way quite intentionally for some reason. This is really hard to place blame, but since the EF code was written by Microsoft, which created the ISerializable interface, I must assume that this other ISafeSerializationData is another related interface that JSON.NET simply doesn't, but should have, accounted for.

Comment: So really, this ball is in JSON.NET's court, which needs to support  ISafeSerializationData. "In versions previous to.NET Framework 4.0, serialization of custom user data in a security transparent code was accomplished using the GetObjectData method. Starting with .NET Framework 4.0, that method is marked with the SecurityCriticalAttribute attribute which prevents execution in security-transparent code. To work around this condition, implement the ISafeSerializationData interface." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.isafeserializationdata(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is still an issue 7 months later, and both JSON.Net (https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/840) and EF (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2895) are completely ignoring it. Serialization of these types is just completely broken, period.  The DataException class that supposedly implements the constructor wouldn't do any good even if it was accessible because the implementation is empty and it doesn't even call the base implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that, for [`ISerializable`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#ISerializable) objects, Json.NET does not support serialization of proxy types defined via the [`SerializationInfo.SetType(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.settype.aspx) method, nor deserialization of proxy objects that implement the [`IObjectReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iobjectreference.aspx) interface that replaces the deserialized proxy with the corresponding "real" object.  Specifically, changing the serialized type during serialization would need to be supported in [`JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeISerializable()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L840) and [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateISerializable()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L1672) -- but it is not.

And as it turns out, exceptions subtypes such as [`DbUpdateConcurrencyException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception.aspx) apparently no longer provide their own streaming constructor, but instead rely on this very proxy mechanism to serialize themselves, in particular setting the [`SerializationInfo.ObjectType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.objecttype.aspx) to the internal type [`SafeSerializationManager`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/safeserializationmanager.cs) -- which, as stated, Json.NET does not support, causing the problem you are seeing.

If your code is running in full trust, as a workaround you can add a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that handles serializing and deserializing of serialization proxies:

```
public class SerializableConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : ISerializable
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var wrapper = serializer.Deserialize<SerializableProxyWrapper>(reader);
        var proxy = wrapper.SerializableValues;
        if (proxy == null)
            return null;
        return proxy.GetRealObject(serializer.Context);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var serializable = (ISerializable)value;
        var proxy = SerializableProxy.ToProxy(serializable, serializer.Context);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new SerializableProxyWrapper { SerializableValues = proxy });
    }
}

sealed class SerializableProxyWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
    public SerializableProxy SerializableValues { get; set; }
}

abstract class SerializableProxy : IObjectReference
{
    public static SerializableProxy ToProxy(ISerializable value, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        SerializationInfo serializationInfo = new SerializationInfo(value.GetType(), new FormatterConverter());
        value.GetObjectData(serializationInfo, context);
        var objectType = serializationInfo.GetObjectType();

        return (SerializableProxy)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SerializableProxy<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { objectType }), new object[] { serializationInfo, context });
    }

    #region IObjectReference Members

    public abstract object GetRealObject(StreamingContext context);

    #endregion
}

[Serializable]
sealed class SerializableProxy<T> : SerializableProxy, ISerializable, IObjectReference where T : ISerializable
{
    SerializationInfo originalInfo;
    StreamingContext context;

    public SerializableProxy(SerializationInfo originalInfo, StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.originalInfo = originalInfo;
        this.context = context;
    }

    #region ISerializable Members

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (SerializationEntry entry in originalInfo)
            info.AddValue(entry.Name, entry.Value, entry.ObjectType);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IObjectReference Members

    public override object GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
    {
        var realObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, 
            new object[] { originalInfo, context }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return realObject.GetFinalRealObject(context);
    }

    #endregion
}

static partial class SerializationExtensions
{
    public static object GetFinalRealObject(this object obj, StreamingContext context)
    {
        while (obj is IObjectReference)
        {
            var realObj = ((IObjectReference)obj).GetRealObject(context);
            if (!(realObj is IObjectReference))
                return realObj;
            if (realObj == obj)
                return realObj; // Avoid an infinite loop
            obj = (IObjectReference)realObj;
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

static partial class SerializationExtensions
{
    public static Type GetObjectType(this SerializationInfo info)
    {
        if (info == null)
            return null;
        return info.ObjectType;
    }
}
```

Then it should be usable as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new [] { new SerializableConverter<Exception>() },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex, settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

However, if your code is not fully trusted, this workaround might fail, and support from Json.NET itself would be required.

Note - tested in some mockup scenarios but not with the actual exceptions you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a contract resolver if you accept to use only base exception fields.
Must be used with TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;

```
public class ISafeSerializationInfoContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        if (contract is JsonISerializableContract)
        {
            JsonISerializableContract serializable = contract as JsonISerializableContract;
            if (serializable.ISerializableCreator == null && typeof(Exception).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
            {
                serializable.ISerializableCreator = p =>
                {
                    SerializationInfo info = (SerializationInfo)p[0];
                    StreamingContext context = (StreamingContext)p[1];

                    Exception exception = (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Exception), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
                    new object[] { info, context }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    object realException = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Exception).GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

                    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
                    {
                        field.SetValue(realException, field.GetValue(exception));
                    }

                    return realException;
                };
            }
        }

        return contract;
    }
}
```