# Binary serialize a .NET Exception-derived class; unit testing with FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have a custom exception that takes in a couple strings in the ctor followed by the usual `Exception innerException` last parameter. The exception class is decorated with `[Serializable]`. This exception class `MyException` also inherits from `MyBaseException` which in turn inherits from `Exception`.

I'm trying to unit test that all the ctor parameters hydrate and dehydrate properly. This works:

```
var error = new MyException("entityname1");
error.Should().BeBinarySerializable();
```

This does not work:

```
var error = new MyException("entityname1",
    new InvalidOperationException("some error"));
error.Should().BeBinarySerializable();
```

It gives:

```
Expected MyException with message "Unable to sign-in “entityname1”."
 to be serializable, but serialization failed with:

Expected member InnerException
to be System.InvalidOperationException with message \"some error\"\n,
but found System.InvalidOperationException with message \"some error\"
```

The error being thrown has no innerException information that might give an idea of the problem.

Interestingly, this works:

```
var error = new MyException("entityname1", new MyOtherException("some error"));
```

Any idea why that one serialization fails and/or how to debug the problem?

.NET 4.6.1 and FluentAssertions 4.14.0

**EDIT:**

Given what @Evk discovered, I tried manually serializing/deserializing an Exception with the `BinaryFormatter` and it seems to work fine:

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

var source = new Exception("some error");

byte[] buffer;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, source);

    buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

    stream.Position = 0;
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    var ex = (Exception)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

    ex.ToString().Should().Be(source.ToString());
}
```

So maybe this is a bug in FluentAssertions.

Comment: Try throwing the inner exception first and checking it in a catch? (this is just a random guess). Also, have you checked [their bug log](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/issues), perhaps even file one of your own?

Comment: Do all of your custom exception types have streaming constructors, as is shown to be required in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422703/how-to-deserialize-object-derived-from-exception-class-using-json-net-c)?  That question is about Json.NET but `BinaryFormatter` uses the same constructor for exception serialization.  Unlike in that question, `BinaryFormatter` requires your constructor to call the `base` constructor.

Comment: Actually the same is reproducable with just "new Exception("some error").Should().BeBinarySerializable();", so it's some bug in FluentAssertion library, not that your exceptions are really not serializable.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain same thing happens if the InvalidOperationException is thrown before adding it to the exception.

Comment: @dbc Yup, they all have the streaming ctor and the GetObjectData method. The exceptions all work as expected except FluentAssertions doesn't seem to like the innerException being non-null.

Comment: @gdoten that's because it doesn't like _any_ default exceptions (Exception, InvalidOperationException and so on) it seems, see my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in FluentAssertions:

[BeBinarySerializable fails with standard .NET exceptions, but not with custom exceptions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions/issues/485)