# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member 'ClassName' was not found

Tags: c#, json.net

What does this error mean exactly?

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Member 'ClassName' was not found.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetElement(String name, Type& foundType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetString(String name)
   at System.Exception..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Void .ctor(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)(Object , Object[] )
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.<>c__DisplayClass10.<CreateISerializableContract>b__f(Object[] args)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateISerializable(JsonReader reader, JsonISerializableContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerProxy.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonFormatterConverter.Convert(Object value, Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetValue(String name, Type type)
   at System.Exception..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Void .ctor(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)(Object , Object[] )
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.<>c__DisplayClass10.<CreateISerializableContract>b__f(Object[] args)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateISerializable(JsonReader reader, JsonISerializableContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
```

Deserialization fails on a complex object with the above error.   Error is also too vague so cannot tell what is wrong here.

**EDIT**
This is not a duplicate of what has been provided as suggestion.  As explained in the problem, the issue occurs only when I use the auto-property initializer.

```
public PayCodeDto PayCode {get; set;} = PayCodeDto.Invalid;
```

PayCode class is simple as follows:

```
  public class PayCodeDto: IEquatable<PayCodeDto>
    {
        public static readonly PayCodeDto Invalid = new PayCodeDto("-1", "Invalid") { DictionaryId = -1 }; 

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int DictionaryId {get;set;}

        public PayCodeDto()
        {
        }

        public PayCodeDto(string id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public override bool IsValid()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
                return false;

            return !Equals(Invalid);
        }

        public bool Equals(PayCodeDto other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
            return string.Equals(Name, other.Name) 
                && string.Equals(Id, other.Id)
                && DictionaryId == other.DictionaryId;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((PayCodeDto) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hashCode = DictionaryId.GetHashCode();
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Id != null ? Id.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);

                return hashCode;
            }
        }
}
```

If I remove the initializer, error no longer occurs.

Comment: Please provide the code where this exception is occurring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deserialize object derived from Exception class using Json.net (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422703/how-to-deserialize-object-derived-from-exception-class-using-json-net-c)