# JSON Exception deserializing into the proper type

Tags: c#, exception, json.net

I need to be able to deserialize in a correct type, and throw a random exception(type can be different) that comes as JSON from webApi. I tried doing it this way, but it comes up with error "type caught or thrown must derive from system.exception"

```
                //genericErrorResponse.ExceptionType = (string)"InvalidLoginException"
                Type exType = Type.GetType(genericErrorResponse.ExceptionType); 
                object ex = Activator.CreateInstance(exType);
                ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(expt); //(string)exception JSON
                throw ex;
```

This is what my incoming JSON looks like:

```
  {
    "ClassName": "InvalidLoginException",
    "Message": "Invalid User Name",
    "Data": {},
    "InnerException": null,
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": "....",
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": "....",
    "HResult": -2147024809,
    "Source": "DB",
    "WatsonBuckets": null,
    "ParamName": null
  }
```

I need to be able to throw "InvalidLoginException"

Code edited Per Brian Roger's comments:

```
        string httpContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        RestResponse<Object> genericResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RestResponse<Object>>(httpContent);
        if(genericResponse.Status.Code == 1074) {

            RestErrorResponse<Exception> genericErrorResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RestErrorResponse<Exception>>(httpContent);

            if (genericErrorResponse.Exception != null)
            {
                Assembly ExAssembly = Assembly.Load("myExceptions");
                Type exType = ExAssembly.GetType(genericErrorResponse.ExceptionType);

                //this is where i probably loose data and unable to reconstruct it anymore
                string expt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(genericErrorResponse.Exception); 

                //but i cannot do SerializeObject(genericErrorResponse.Exception, exType)
                //I Also cannot do JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RestResponse<exType>>(httpContent)

                //this will not deserealize it anymore
                Exception ex = (Exception)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(expt, exType);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Complete REST response:

```
{
  "Exception": {
    "ClassName": "InvalidLoginException",
    "Message": "Invalid User Name",
    "Data": {},
    "InnerException": null,
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": "....",
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": "....",
    "HResult": -2147024809,
    "Source": "DB",
    "WatsonBuckets": null,
    "ParamName": null
  },
  "Status": {
    "Verbal": "Error",
    "Code": 1074
  },
  "Content": null
}
```

Comment: @BrianRogers, but how do i fix "type caught or thrown must derive from system.exception"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the exception type to `DeserializeObject`.  Otherwise it will deserialize to a `JObject`, which obviously cannot be cast to an `Exception`.  Also, you do not need to create an instance of the `Exception` first; that serves no purpose.  Try it like this:

```
Type exType = Type.GetType(genericErrorResponse.ExceptionType, true); 
Exception ex = (Exception)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(expt, exType);
throw ex;
```

One other important note: your custom exception will need to have a constructor that accepts a `SerializationInfo` and a `StreamingContext` as shown below, otherwise it will not be able to be deserialized.

```
public class InvalidLoginException: Exception
{
    public InvalidLoginException()
    {
    }

    public InvalidLoginException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Based on your edits, it looks like your JSON is somewhat variable and you are trying to deserialize it and reserialize it multiple times in order to figure out what you've actually got.  Because of this variability, I would recommend deserializing into a `JObject` first.  This will make it easier to poke around without having to worry about matching it up to specific classes.  Once you know what you have, you can use the `ToObject()` method to convert the data part of the JSON into the target class.  Here is how I would go about detecting the exception and then converting into an actual `Exception` instance:

```
string httpContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject responseObject = JObject.Parse(httpContent);
int statusCode = (int)responseObject.SelectToken("Status.Code");

if (statusCode == 1074)
{
    string exceptionClassName = (string)responseObject.SelectToken("Exception.ClassName");
    Assembly exAssembly = Assembly.Load("myExceptions");
    Type exType = exAssembly.GetType(exceptionClassName, false);
    if (exType != null)
    {
        Exception ex = (Exception)responseObject["Exception"].ToObject(exType);
        throw ex;
    }
    else
    {
        // exception class was not found, so just throw a generic one
        string message = (string)responseObject.SelectToken("Exception.Message");
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will produce "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Exception'." and even if this would work, will throw Exception instead of InvalidLoginException?

Comment: Make sure that `exType` is not null; that is, `GetType` is actually finding the type in your assembly.  The type name needs to be the full assembly qualified name in order for `GetType` to find it.  If you're just using a simple class name then you'll need to provide an assembly resolver function to resolve the type, or else use a different method like `Assembly.GetType()`.

Comment: I ended up using Assembly.GetType(); it now gives me: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Member 'ParamName' was not found.'

Comment: I'm not sure why you would be getting that exception.  I tried an example locally and was able to deserialize a custom InvalidLoginException from your JSON.  See [How to deserialize object derived from Exception class using Json.net (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3422703/10263) for more ideas on deserializing custom exceptions.

Comment: I updated the question, It is now showing complete code. 'ParamName' is a part of JSON that gets lost probably

Comment: I wonder how would this work if I will have a generic exception thrown on server, the one that doesn't belong to "Assembly.Load("myExceptions");"

Comment: You can add conditional logic to try to get the type from your assembly first and if it's not found, then just get the exception message string from the json and throw a plain vanilla `Exception` using that message.  I've updated my answer to show that approach.  You could of course embellish it to search additional assemblies, or even use a lookup table mapping class names to known exception types instead.  I'll leave those details up to you.